# User defined SVM kernel with scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I encounter a problem when defining a kernel by myself in scikit-learn.
I define by myself the gaussian kernel and was able to fit the SVM but not to use it to make a prediction.

More precisely I have the following code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import numpy as np


digits = load_digits(2)
X, y = shuffle(digits.data, digits.target)

gamma = 1.0


X_train, X_test = X[:100, :], X[100:, :]
y_train, y_test = y[:100], y[100:]

m1 = SVC(kernel='rbf',gamma=1)
m1.fit(X_train, y_train)
m1.predict(X_test)

def my_kernel(x,y):
    d = x - y
    c = np.dot(d,d.T)
    return np.exp(-gamma*c)

m2 = SVC(kernel=my_kernel)
m2.fit(X_train, y_train)
m2.predict(X_test)
```

m1 and m2 should be the same, but m2.predict(X_test) return the error :

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (260,64) (100,64)

I don't understand the problem.

Furthermore if x is one data point, the m1.predict(x) gives a +1/-1 result, as expexcted, but m2.predict(x) gives an array of +1/-1...
No idea why.

Comment: Your kernel function is wrong.

Comment: Any more precision ? The kernel function I want to use is K(x,y) = exp(- gamma * || x-y||^2), what is the problem ?

Comment: I mean your implementation of `my_kernel` is wrong, as indicated by the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is at the `x - y` line. You cannot subtract the two like that, because the first dimensions of both may not be equal. Here is how the `rbf` kernel is implemented in scikit-learn, taken from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py) (only keeping the essentials):

```
def row_norms(X, squared=False):

    if issparse(X):
        norms = csr_row_norms(X)
    else:
        norms = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', X, X)

    if not squared:
        np.sqrt(norms, norms)
    return norms

def euclidean_distances(X, Y=None, Y_norm_squared=None, squared=False):
   """
    Considering the rows of X (and Y=X) as vectors, compute the
    distance matrix between each pair of vectors.

    [...]


    Returns
    -------
    distances : {array, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples_1, n_samples_2)
   """
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)

    if Y_norm_squared is not None:
        YY = check_array(Y_norm_squared)
        if YY.shape != (1, Y.shape[0]):
            raise ValueError(
                "Incompatible dimensions for Y and Y_norm_squared")
    else:
        YY = row_norms(Y, squared=True)[np.newaxis, :]

    if X is Y:  # shortcut in the common case euclidean_distances(X, X)
        XX = YY.T
    else:
        XX = row_norms(X, squared=True)[:, np.newaxis]

    distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
    distances *= -2
    distances += XX
    distances += YY
    np.maximum(distances, 0, out=distances)

    if X is Y:
        # Ensure that distances between vectors and themselves are set to 0.0.
        # This may not be the case due to floating point rounding errors.
        distances.flat[::distances.shape[0] + 1] = 0.0

    return distances if squared else np.sqrt(distances, out=distances)

def rbf_kernel(X, Y=None, gamma=None):

    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
    if gamma is None:
        gamma = 1.0 / X.shape[1]

    K = euclidean_distances(X, Y, squared=True)
    K *= -gamma
    np.exp(K, K)    # exponentiate K in-place
    return K
```

You might want to dig deeper into the code, but look at the comments for the `euclidean_distances` function. A naive implementation of what you're trying to achieve would be this:

```
def my_kernel(x,y):
    d = np.zeros((x.shape[0], y.shape[0]))
    for i, row_x in enumerate(x):
        for j, row_y in enumerate(y):
            d[i, j] = np.exp(-gamma * np.linalg.norm(row_x - row_y))

    return d
```

Comment: I have been following the same train of thoughts as you and trying to make it actually work on the dataset. After importing [sklearn pairwise.euclidean_distances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html), I can't seem to make it work... `euclidean_distances(X, y)` will return a ValueError: incompatible dimensions for X and Y matrices.

Comment: @JulienMarrec what have you done? `euclidean_distances` works for me.

Comment: @JulienMarrec - what are you passing to it? The last dimension of the two should be equal (same number of columns)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll go on with that. I just want to point out that it is really unclear that a user defined kernel function should take two matrix of data. In particular the examples available on the web can be understood as a kernel function taking two datapoint as argument and returning a real number.

Comment: @IVlad, I'm passing it the X, y from the original post above
`digits = load_digits(2)`
`X, y = shuffle(digits.data, digits.target)`

Comment: @JulienMarrec that is not what you're supposed to pass. Both parameters should have the second dimensions equal. You want to pass two subsets of `X`.

Comment: @JulienMarrec if X1 and X2 are two matrices, each row representing one data points, euclidean distance return a matric of the distance between the rows.

Comment: I agree, the docs / example are bad :-/ See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5043 The docs here http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels say that the callable needs to take "matrices" though it is not very explicit.